# Translation between grid index and actual values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a grid of shape `(A1, M1, A2, M2, A3, M3, E)` which I generated using

```
A1, M1, A2, M2, A3, M3, E = meshgrid(Grid.aGrid, Grid.mGrid, Grid.aGrid, Grid.mGrid, Grid.aGrid, Grid.mGrid, Grid.eGrid, indexing='ij')
```

, where `Grid.aGrid` is generated using `linspace(aMin, aMax, nA)`, and similarly for the other grids.

Consider some `Z = f(A1, ...)`, where `f()` will mark some grid points as irrelevant. For simplicity, let it be

```
Z = A1 + A2 + A3
Z[Z < 0] = NaN
```

Consider `Z[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. It contains the value corresponding to the real values `(aGrid[0], mGrid[1],  aGrid[2], mGrid[3], aGrid[4], mGrid[5], eGrid[6])`. This is exactly what I try to achieve for all points on `Z` that are not marked by `f()`:

I want to create a dictionary

```
foo = {z1, z2, z3, ... zn}
```

where `z1` etc are all of the kind

```
z1 = (aGrid[0], mGrid[1],  aGrid[2], mGrid[3], aGrid[4], mGrid[5], eGrid[6])
```

, which is the grid-values corresponding to the position of `z1` inside `Z`.

I came up with something:

```
aGrid = arange(0, 10)
mGrid = arange(100, 110)
eGrid = arange(1000, 1200)

A,M,E = meshgrid(aGrid, mGrid, eGrid, indexing='ij')

# contains the grid index
Z = (A + M + E).astype(float)
Z[A < 3] = nan
# will contain the actual values, as tuples
Z2 = {}

for i, idx in enumerate(ndindex(Z.shape)):
    a = aGrid[idx[0]]
    m = mGrid[idx[1]]
    e = eGrid[idx[2]]

    if isnan(Z[idx]):
        Z2[i] = NaN
    else:
        Z2[i] = (a, m, e)
```

**Efficiency is key. Is there any faster/cleaner way I could achieve this? Any alternative to using a dictionary?**

I especially dislike that I have to write down `aGrid[idx[0]]` etc. Is it possible to keep the algorithm more general? Some thing along the lines of

```
for i, idx in enumerate(ndindex(Z.shape)):
    # some magic happens here. What exactly?
    someMagicList = magic(aGrid, mGrid, eGrid)
    Z2[i] = someMagicList[idx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `broadcast_arrays()`, and the result `Z2` is an array with shape `(20000, 3)`.

```
import numpy as np

aGrid = np.arange(0, 10, dtype=float)
mGrid = np.arange(100, 110, dtype=float)
eGrid = np.arange(1000, 1200, dtype=float)

A,M,E = np.meshgrid(aGrid, mGrid, eGrid, indexing='ij')

# contains the grid index
Z = (A + M + E).astype(float)
Z[A < 3] = np.nan

grids = [A, M, E]
grid_bc = np.broadcast_arrays(*grids)
Z2 = np.column_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid_bc])
Z2[np.isnan(Z.ravel())] = np.nan

print Z2[5900], Z2[6000]
```

Comment: This looks like a great improvement of efficiency over what I am doing. As I am trying to work this into my script; one short follow-up if I may (I presume this is too short for a new question): How do I (efficiently) get the subset of those that are not `NaN`? `statesRelevant = [z for z in states if not np.isnan(z.any())]` got all of them in. Apparently, `isnan()` didnt work to select those out that had `(nan,...)` in them.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is `states`? do you means `Z[~np.isnan(Z)]` or `Z2[~np.isnan(Z)]`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean `Z2`. Using `Z` as the indicator for `isnan()` is nice, but what if I were only left with `Z2`? I'm planning to pass along only `Z2` through the functions that process it.

Comment: how about `Z2[~np.isnan(Z2[:, 0])]`

Comment: Could you perhaps also have a look at the following question? It's related to this one and has not received enough attention so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981232/correspondence-between-a-ij-meshgrid-and-a-long-meshgrid