# Correspondence between a "ij" meshgrid and a long meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a matrix `Z` that contains grid-based results for `z = z(a,m,e)`. `Z` has shape `(len(aGrid), len(mGrid), len(eGrid))`. `Z[0,1,2]` contains the `z(a=aGrid[0], m=mGrid[1], e=eGrid[2])`. However, we may have removed some elements from the state space from the object (for example and simplicity, `(a,m,e : a > 3)`. Say that the size of the valid state space is `x`.

I [have been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714554/translation-between-grid-index-and-actual-values) a code to transform this object to an object `Z2` of shape `(x, 3)`. Every row in `Z2` corresponds to an element `i` from `Z2`: `(aGrid[a[i]], mGrid[m[i]], eGrid[e[i]])`.

```
# first create Z, a mesh grid based matrix that has some invalid states (we set them to NaN)
aGrid = np.arange(0, 10, dtype=float)
mGrid = np.arange(100, 110, dtype=float)
eGrid = np.arange(1000, 1200, dtype=float)
A,M,E = np.meshgrid(aGrid, mGrid, eGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = A
Z[Z > 3] = np.NaN #remove some states from being "allowed"

# now, translate them from shape (len(aGrid), len(mGrid), len(eGrid)) to 
grids = [A,M,E]
grid_bc = np.broadcast_arrays(*grids)
Z2 = np.column_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid_bc])
Z2[np.isnan(Z.ravel())] = np.nan
Z3 = Z2[~np.isnan(Z2)]
```

Through some computation, I then get a matrix `V4` that has the shape of `Z3` but contains **4** columns.

I am given

- `Z2` (as above)
- `Z3` (as above)
- `V4` which is a matrix shape (`Z3.shape[0], Z3.shape[1]+1`): **it has an additional column appended**
- (if necessary, I still have access to the grid `A,M,E`)

and I need to recreate

- `V`, which is the matrix that contains the values (of the last column) of `V4`, but is transformed back to the shape of `Z1`.

That is, if there is a row in `V4` that reads `(aGrid[0], mGrid[1], eGrid[2], v1)`, then the the value of `V` at `V[0,1,2] = v1`, etc. for all rows in `V4`,

**Efficiency is key**.

Comment: Z = A;
Z[Z > 3] = np.NaN; here you also set values in A.

Comment: Good find. In the trivial example this is true, in my real code I have something like `Z  = A + M**2 ....`. Anyhow, A,M,E are only invoked in order to get the correct shape for `Z` and to remove invalid states, so this is not too important.

Comment: Since you remove elements from Z2, you cannot unambiguously recreate Z. What information will you have access to? To the number and shape of arrays in grids? I wonder why you need to step forward and back in this way.

Comment: Well, actually, I do not want to transform back `Z2`. I have a result of computation that has *the shape of Z2*, but different values, which I want to get back into the original format on the `ij`-Grid. I could save the intermediate version of `Z2` (the one with the `NaN` markers, before they are dropped) - maybe that helps because then you have the position of the `NaN`, i.e. where the final `Z2`-formatted data has missing items. Otherwise, what else would you need?

Comment: Currently there’s still a contradiction in your question -- Z2 and Z3 only have 3 columns in your code, yet in the text you define them as having a fourth (the actual value at the grid coordinates specified by the first three columns).

Comment: I am terribly sorry: you are indeed correct. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your original problem conditions, recreated as follows, modified such that `A` is a *copy* of `Z`:

```
aGrid = np.arange(0, 10, dtype=float)
mGrid = np.arange(100, 110, dtype=float)
eGrid = np.arange(1000, 1200, dtype=float)
A,M,E = np.meshgrid(aGrid, mGrid, eGrid, indexing='ij')
Z = A.copy()
Z[Z > 3] = np.NaN 

grids = [A,M,E]
grid_bc = np.broadcast_arrays(*grids)
Z2 = np.column_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid_bc])
Z2[np.isnan(Z.ravel())] = np.nan
Z3 = Z2[~np.isnan(Z2)]
```

A function can be defined as follows, to recreate a dense N-D matrix from a sparse 2D `# data points` x `# dims + 1` matrix. The first argument of the function is the aformentioned 2D matrix, the last (optional) arguments are the grid indexes for each dimension:

```
import numpy as np
def map_array_to_index(uniq_arr):
    return np.vectorize(dict(map(reversed, enumerate(uniq_arr))).__getitem__)

def recreate(arr, *coord_arrays):
    if len(coord_arrays) != arr.shape[1] - 1:
      coord_arrays = map(np.unique, arr.T[0:-1])
    lookups = map(map_array_to_index, coord_arrays)
    new_array = np.nan * np.ones(map(len, coord_arrays))
    new_array[tuple(l(c) for c, l in zip(arr.T[0:-1], lookups))] = arr[:, -1]
    new_grids = np.meshgrid(*coord_arrays, indexing='ij')
    return new_array, new_grids
```

Given a 2D matrix V4, defined above with values derived from Z,

```
V4 = np.column_stack([g.ravel() for g in grid_bc] + [Z.ravel()])
```

it is possible to recreate Z as follows:

```
V4_orig_form, V4_grids = recreate(V4, aGrid, mGrid, eGrid)
```

All non-NaN values correctly test for equality:

```
np.all(Z[~np.isnan(Z)] == V4_orig_form[~np.isnan(V4_orig_form)])
```

The function also works without aGrid, mGrid, eGrid passed in, but in this case it will not include any coordinate that is not present in the corresponding column of the input array.

Comment: I missed the edit of your answer until now, sorry about that! Right now I'm trying to understand what's happening. I'm following exactly your paste, but getting a `KeyError: 100.0` at the line starting with `new_array[tuple...`.

Comment: Oops. Please see my latest edit - the example works now. (The function that maps grid coordinates to N-D array indexes had the map the wrong way round.)

Answer (score 0):

So Z is the same shape as A,M,E; and Z2 is the shape (Z.ravel(),len(grids)) = (10x10x200, 3) in this case (if you do not filter out the NaN elements).
This is how you recreate your grids from the values of `Z2`:

```
grids = Z2.T
A,M,E = [g.reshape(A.shape) for g in grids]
Z = A # or whatever other calculation you need here
```

The only thing you need is the shape to which you want to go back. `NaN` will propagate to the final array.